# Disable date ranges using bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I disable multiple date ranges? using `bootstrap-datepicker`

Currently this is my code on how to disable dates specifically.

```
  <div id="input-daterange" class="input-group input-daterange" data-date-format="M d, yyyy">
                                <input type="text" id="starts_at" name="starts_at" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Arrival:" value="{{ $property_request->starts_at != '' ? date('M j, Y',strtotime($property_request->starts_at)) : '' }}">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" id="ends_at" name="ends_at" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Departure:" value="{{ $property_request->ends_at != '' ? date('M j, Y',strtotime($property_request->ends_at)) : '' }}">
                            </div>
    var date = new Date();
    var arrayDates = ['May 20, 2020','May 23, 2020'];
    $('#input-daterange').datepicker({
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        format: "M d, yyyy",
        clearBtn : true,
        datesDisabled: arrayDates,
        startDate : date
    });
```

[image]

As you notice, `May 20, 2020` and `May 23, 2020` are placed inside the array.

and these 2 dates is being disabled. But `May 22, 2020` and  `May 21, 2020` are not being disabled since that way of code is disabling dates specifically

But what I'm trying to do is to disable dates between date ranges.

So if I have 3 different date ranges

`May 20, 2020` to `May 23, 2020`

`May 24, 2020` to `May 26, 2020`

`May 27, 2020` to `May 29, 2020`

This should be disables the date ranges.

The reason why I'm doing this is because I have multiple rows of date range from `db`

something like this:  *(These dates will be converted to `M j, Y` format using php disregard the date format of json)*

```
{
   "starts_at": "2020-05-20",
   "ends_at": "2020-05-23"
},
{
   "starts_at": "2020-05-24",
   "ends_at": "2020-05-26"
},
{
   "starts_at": "2020-05-27",
   "ends_at": "2020-05-29"
}
```

In addition I tried to based here but ain't helping

[Disable few date ranges in Bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199372/disable-few-date-ranges-in-bootstrap-datepicker)

This is the plugin that Im using

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: have you tried `['2020-05-20','2020-05-21']` instead of `var arrayDates = ['May 20, 2020','May 21, 2020']`?

Comment: Disabling dates specifically is working fine as stated above. My preferred date format is `M j, Y` tried also to change the date format like that and didn't work/

Comment: The documentation says [datesDisabled](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdatesdisabled) is how it's done. Also, when comparing dates, it's best to use YMD. It's the simplest. `m j, Y` Preference is good for display & what the user sees, but there is no better way to compare dates YMD.

Comment: can u enlighten me on dateDisabled I know how to use it for specific dates but not on the multiple date ranges

Comment: You're looking to disable the dates between the selected dates correct? So in your example using, May 20, 2020 to May 23, 2020, you want to also disable May 21st and May 22nd, right? I assume each of these user selections creates an array with the start and finish date right?

Comment: Those dates of  `starts_at` and `ends_at` are coming from my database. I can access those records. The problem is if I assign those records to `var arrayDates` it will only populates the `starts_at` and `ends_at` but not the expanded dates of those date ranges that's why some of the date ranges is not being disable. I'm looking for something If I placed a date range it will automatically disables the dates between 2 date ranges. Because `datesDisabled` here is just disables dates specifically

Comment: Can you add a snippit with all relevant code and external libraries please?